# jquery cannot read json object and display the data

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to call a webmethod and get json object and display the data in aspx file with jquery. but something s wrong and it is not working. I will explain with the code below

here is the webmethod

```
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("Connection String2");
        DbCommand dbCommand;
        dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("MedBul_Select_Selected_Professional");
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "id", DbType.Int16, Convert.ToInt16(id));
        IDataReader dr = db.ExecuteReader(dbCommand);
        if(dr.Read())
        {
            int p_id = Convert.ToInt16(dr["ProfessionalID"].ToString());
            string firstname = dr["ProfessionalName"].ToString();
            string lastname = dr["ProfessionalSurname"].ToString();
            int prefix = Convert.ToInt16(dr["PrefixID"].ToString());
            int gender = Convert.ToInt16(dr["Gender"].ToString());
            string birthdate = dr["BirthDate"].ToString();
            string mobilephone = dr["MobilePhone"].ToString();
            string email = dr["Email"].ToString();
            string diplomano = dr["DiplomaNo"].ToString();

            return_str += "[{\"id\":\"" + p_id + "\",\"firstname\":\"" + firstname + "\",\"lastname\":\"" + lastname + "\",\"prefix\":\"" + prefix + "\",\"gender\":\"" + gender + "\",\"birthdate\":\"" + birthdate + "\",\"mobilephone\":\"" + mobilephone + "\",\"email\":\"" + email + "\",\"diplomano\":\"" + diplomano + "\"}]";
        }
```

and here is the jquery code.

```
  $('#btn_second').click(function () {
            //$('#txt_isim_4').val('test arif');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Registration.aspx/get_selected_professional",
                data: "{'id':'2'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        alert(value);
                        alert(value.d);
                        alert(index);
                        alert(value.firstname);
                    });

                }
            });
        });
```

I am trying to alert() what is returned but It doesnt display anything. I am very sure that I can get the data from Database and parse it properly....

What is wrong with my code? How can I get it done to display the json object?

Comment: Did you inspect the data and see whether data is present?

Comment: show your json results.

Comment: post your data object too...

Comment: check your browser console for any errors

Comment: how can I get the json object to display? I dont know how to inspect it?

Comment: i don't know in asp.net but in php  `header("Content-type: application/json");` is needed is there something like this in asp?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ - I think you have not parsed your JSON string into what Javascript can use as a object.

Comment: try this `success: function (data) { console.log(data);..` and check you firebug console if using firfox.. else check your chrome developers tool   > console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seeing your response..

```
return_str += "[{\"id\":\"" + p_id + "\",\"firstname\":\"" + firstname + "\",\"lastname\":\"" + lastname + "\",\"prefix\":\"" + prefix + "\",\"gender\":\"" + gender + "\",\"birthdate\":\"" + birthdate + "\",\"mobilephone\":\"" + mobilephone + "\",\"email\":\"" + email + "\",\"diplomano\":\"" + diplomano + "\"}]";
```

no need to use `each` loop.. since in `ajax` you have mentioned `dataType` as `json`.. use `.` operator to get the objects

try this

```
success: function (data) {
              alert(data.id);
              alert(data.firstname); // similar for others
            }
```

Comment: as its array of objects shouldn't it be like `data[0].id`

Comment: no... the `dataType:'json'` of ajax will automatically parse it for you.. try it out.. :)

Answer (score 0):

i assume the returned json looks like

```
var $json ='[{"id":"1","name":"john"},{"id":"2","name":"smith"}]';
var json = $.parseJSON($json);//will already be parsed in your callback function bcoz of the dataType:json
```

try modifying your loop like

```
$.each(json,function(i,j){
    $(j).each(function(k,v){
     console.log(v.id);
     console.log(v.name);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Eu9Pp/